# Algorithmic T(n) = T(n-1)+2

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity

How do i apply the Master Theorem on this equation?

if T(1) = 1 and

T(n) = T(n-1)+2

**What would be the runtime of such a program?**
What is the T(1) = 1 for?
Which case is this and why? 
Please an detailed explanation. Thanks.

Comment: T(1) = 1 is the terminal condition.  It is the one reached when given T(n) for some number n through repeated application of the relation T(n)=T(n-1)+2.

Comment: thanks yes i got this one now so i have a Condition T(1) = 1. I have a term T(n) = T(n-1) + 2. So lets start with 2. I have T(2) = T(1) + 2 == 3; T(3) = T(2) + 2 ==  The solution of T(2) is 3 + 2; T(4) = T(3) + 2 == 7;

Comment: To emphasize amit's answer below, consider the generic form shown at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Master Theorem here (without variable substitution at least) here, since it is not in the correct format.

Your function however is easy to analyze and is in `Theta(n)`.

Proof by induction, `T(k) <= 2k` for each `k<n`

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 2 <= 2(n-1) + 2 = 2n -2 + 2 <= 2n
                   ^
               induction 
               hypothesis
```

Base of induction is `T(1) = 1 <= 2`

The above shows that `T(n)` is in `O(n)`, since we found `c=2` such that for `n>0`, the following is correct: `T(n) <= c*n`, and this is the [definition of big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).

Proving similarly that `T(n)` is in `Omega(n)` is easy, and from this you can conclude `T(n)` is in `Theta(n)`

Comment: why is it in Theta(n)? How did you conclude that?

Comment: @MatthiasKöhler I proved it by induction.

Comment: I am sorry but i still didn´t understand it. I am very poor at mathematics and i am trying hard to learn so forgive me if i dont understand your answer yet. So for example. Why do you say T(k) <= 2k? My equoation T(n) = T(n-1) +2 has no k or 2k. Why do you start like that? I appreciate your help very much

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. So with the help of you answer and a new recursiv equation i think i finally understood it. Lets say i have T(N) = 1*T(n-1) + n^2. Master Theorem doesn´t apply here aswell so i have my base case.

```
T(1) = 1
T(2) = 5
T(3) = 14
T(4) = 30

--> Proof by induction, T(k) <= 2k for each k<n

T(n) = T(n-1) + n^2 <= n^2(n-1) + n^2 = n^3 - n^2 + n^2 = n^3
                    ^
                induction 
                hypothesis
So this leads to O(N^3) ? not sure about this. Why not Omega or Theta.
```

When would my hypothesis/induction be <, > or >=.